# Unix Command for counting number of words which contains letter combination (with repeats and letters in between)

Tags: unix, grep

How would you count the number of words in a text file which contains all of the letters a, b, and c. These letters may occur more than once in the word and the word may contain other letters as well. (For example, "cabby" should be counted.)

Using sample input which should return 2:

```
abc abb cabby
```

I tried both:

```
grep -E "[abc]" test.txt | wc -l 

grep 'abcdef' testCount.txt | wc -l
```

both of which return 1 instead of 2.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` and use the return value of `sub` function. If successful substitution is made, the return value of the `sub` function will be the number of substitutions done.

```
$ echo "abc abb cabby" | 
awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
    if(sub(/a/,"",$i)>0 && sub(/b/,"",$i)>0 && sub(/c/,"",$i)>0) {
        count+=1
    }
}
END{print count}'
2
```

We keep the condition of return value to be greater than 0 for all three alphabets. The `for loop` will iterate over every word of every line adding the counter when all three alphabets are found in the word.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get around using multiple invocations of `grep`. Thus I would go with (GNU grep):

```
<file grep -ow '\w+' | grep a | grep b | grep c
```

Output:

```
abc
cabby
```

The first `grep` puts each word on a line of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work

#### sed 's/ /\n/g' test.txt |grep a |grep b|grep c

#### $ cat test.txt

abc abb cabby

#### $ sed 's/ /\n/g' test.txt |grep a |grep b|grep c

abc
cabby

hope this helps..